# Calculate LPAR CPU utilization (AIX)

Tags: aix, cpu, math

I'm trying to calculate the CPU utilization of an LPAR but I get wrong results.
I can see the utilization in the HMC Web Interface, but Id like to calculate it myself for own purposes.

My test: I take an LPAR that has 0.2 EC and current utilization of 0.6 (0.6/0.2 = 3 -> 300%). So I am to expect 300% from this particular LPAR.

I login to the HMC, and run

> lslparutil -m MachineName -r lpar -n 2 --filter lpar_names=lparName -F
> time,capped_cycles,uncapped_cycles,entitled_cycles

I get the values from the last two minutes

> 04/26/2017 13:21:43,294282846772027,683494280098951,1050755263230847
>
> 04/26/2017 13:20:43,294273753737790,683455429211045,1050746050402243

I then use the formula to calculate processor utilization from IBMs manual on lslparutil (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/8408-E8E/p8edm/lslparutil.html)

Processor utilization % = ((capped_cycles + uncapped_cycles) / entitled_cycles) * 100

Processor utilization % = (((294282846772027 - 294273753737790) + (683494280098951 - 683455429211045)) /  (1050755263230847 - 1050746050402243)) * 100

Processor utilization % = 520.40%

I get a processor utilization of 520%, not 300%. Something seems way off here. What could it be?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you get from lslparutil is actually correct in your case. What you see in the Web Interface are not what you think it is. It's related to the physical usage. Hope that clears things up